# MAC OS X - screencast

Tags: mac-osx

what can I use to record an screencast at os x leopard?
Freeware are prefered.

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really can't spend any money, take a look at [ScreenCastle](http://screencastle.com/).  It's a web-based (uses Java) tool that works cross platform.

That said, on a mac, some of the greatest screencasts I have seen have been made with [ScreenFlow](http://www.telestream.net/screen-flow/overview.htm) ($99).  It is very easy to use, has built in editing ability, and has great high end features.  But it is not free.

Comment: ScreenFlow trial I think solves my current need. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I have been impressed with [Jing](http://www.jingproject.com/).  It allows you to take screencasts and screenshots and share them easily.

Answer (score 2):

Another reason to hold off on investing in a screen recording tool right now, OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard) has one built-in:  [Screen Recording in Snow Leopard's Quicktime X](http://www.appleinsider.com/articles/09/04/24/snow_leopard_to_offer_screen_recording_via_quicktime_x_player.html)

Answer (score 0):

[iShowU HD](http://www.shinywhitebox.com/ishowuhd/main.html) is well worth the $30.

Answer (score 0):

If you've configured the Podcast Producer service on your OS X Server then the obvious answer would be to use Podcast Capture on the client since ***it already comes with Mac OS***.

See: http://www.apple.com/server/macosx/features/podcasts.html